# CSS Overflow: relative height with bottom absolute positionning

Tags: css, overflow, positioning

Yes, another annoying overflow question on css...

Here is my case:

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    Some short content that may take a line or two.
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    Some short to very long content that may overflow parent div...
  </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}

#child1 {
}
#child2 {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

As you can see I want child2 to overflow the parent div when needed. But as I don't know the exact height of child2 (because child1 may vary a bit) I'm not able to do some absolute positionning as I'm used to with `bottom: 0px` and `top: ???px`.

Some JSFiddle to play with : https://jsfiddle.net/6r3ojecL/1/

In the worst case I will use some ugly JS code snippet, but I'll be happy if I could to master css once again. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `display: flex`. Check the [**updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6r3ojecL/2/)

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#child1 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#child2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2">
    child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content child 2 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox does not work in IE9 and lower. Not suitable for production.

Comment: Nice! I have now to learn more about flex, seems pretty useful. Thanks Pugazh.

Comment: @JoostS Damn IE... always a source of exceptions since 95! *sigh*

Comment: Display table is the cross browser alternative for flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow on the parent and not on the child (updated).

CSS

```
#parent {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100px; 
 overflow: auto; 
} 
#child1 { } 
#child2 { }
```